# TS Generics: TS2345: Argument of type string | number | symbol is not assignable to parameter of type never

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to make a sorting function for an array of objects based on the keys but being too generic throws TS error.

Here is the sorting function

```
// sort.ts

export type SortOrder = "asc" | "desc";

const descendingComparator = <T extends any>(a: T, b: T, sortBy: keyof T) => {
  if (b[sortBy] < a[sortBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[sortBy] > a[sortBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
};

export const createSortComparator = <T extends object, Key extends keyof T>(
  sortOrder: SortOrder,
  sortBy: Key
): ((a: { [key in Key]: T[Key] }, b: { [key in Key]: T[Key] }) => number) =>
  sortOrder === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, sortBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, sortBy);
```

and here is the usage

```
  enum DummyKeys {
    supplierName = "supplierName",
    supplierId = "supplierId"
  }

  type Dummy = {
    [DummyKeys.supplierName]: string;
    [DummyKeys.supplierId]: number;
  };

  const dummy: Dummy[] = [
    { [DummyKeys.supplierName]: "test", [DummyKeys.supplierId]: 123 }
  ];

  const sortedDummy = dummy.sort(
    createSortComparator("asc", DummyKeys.supplierName)
  );

  const sortStuff = <T extends object, Key extends keyof T>(
    objToSort: T[],
    keyToSort: Key
  ) => { 
    // HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWING
    objToSort.sort(createSortComparator("asc", keyToSort)); // If i cast keyToSort as never, it works, anything else it wont.
  };

  sortStuff(dummy, DummyKeys.supplierName);
```

This won't work either

```
  const sortStuff = <T extends Dummy, Key extends keyof T>(
    objToSort: T[],
    keyToSort: Key
  ) => {
    objToSort.sort(createSortComparator("asc", keyToSort));
  };
```

This will eventually work but now is not too generic anymore

```
  const sortStuff = <T extends Dummy, Key extends keyof Dummy>(
    objToSort: T[],
    keyToSort: Key
  ) => {
    objToSort.sort(createSortComparator("asc", keyToSort));
  };
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my sort is too complicated. The problem is TS do not know who keyToSort is.

Solution is to make types less complicated:

```
// sort.ts

export type SortOrder = "asc" | "desc";

const descendingComparator = <T extends object>(
  a: T,
  b: T,
  sortBy: keyof T
) => {
  if (b[sortBy] < a[sortBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[sortBy] > a[sortBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
};

export const createSortComparator = <T extends object>(
  sortOrder: SortOrder,
  sortBy: keyof T
): ((a: T, b: T) => number) =>
  sortOrder === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, sortBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, sortBy);
```

this would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your original code is that your call to `createSortComparator` does not have any information regarding the type `T`, which means that as far as it is concerned there is no key that fits.

In this case you have to manually pass the generic types to the call

```
const sortStuff = <T extends object, Key extends keyof T>(
    objToSort: T[],
    keyToSort: Key
  ) => { 
    // Add the generic types to the call here to pass them on
    objToSort.sort(createSortComparator<T,Key>("asc", keyToSort));
  };
```

Hope this helps